# Visual Studio C# 2015 não para de debugar

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte:

1. Compilo o programa clicando em iniciar;
2. A tela *splash* é exibida, a barra de progresso roda e chega a 100% (fecha a tela de *splash*);
3. Abre a tela de *login*, coloca-se a identificação e tudo ocorre corretamente (a tela de identificação é fechada);
4. Abre a tela *home* (principal), sendo que ao fechar a tela *home* pelo <kbd>X</kbd> (ainda não coloquei os outros botões) o Visual Studio continua rodando, a compilação não para até que eu aperte o botão parar do Visual Studio.

O que gostaria que acontecesse, quando inserisse usuário e senha, a tela de *login* fosse fechada e aparecesse apenas a tela *home*.

O que estou fazendo de errado??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace App.Sis_Igreja
{
    public partial class frm_inicial : Form
    {
        public frm_inicial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String usuario = tb_usuario.Text;
        String senha = tb_senha.Text;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(senha)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor preencha todos os campos!!");
        }else
        {
            String config = "server=localhost; userid=root; pwd=root; database=sis_igreja";
            MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection(config);
            MySqlCommand Query = new MySqlCommand();
            Query.Connection = conexao;
            conexao.Open();
            Query.CommandText = "select usuario, senha from login where usuario = '" + usuario + "' and senha = '" + senha + "'";
            bool verifica = Query.ExecuteReader().HasRows;

        if (verifica == true)
        {
                String titulo = "Bem Vindo";
                String mensagem = "Usuário Logado com Sucesso";
                MessageBox.Show(titulo, mensagem);
                MessageBoxButtons botao = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
                //DialogResult resultado = ;
                if( botao == MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
                frm_gerenciamento frm = new frm_gerenciamento();
                frm.Show();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nome do usuário ou senha incorreto!");
        }
        conexao.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App.Sis_Igreja
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Ponto de entrada principal para o aplicativo.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

> Segue o form da Splash

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App.Sis_Igreja
{
    public partial class SplashScreen : Form
    {
        public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb_porcentagem.Text = pb_splash.Value + "%";

            if (pb_splash.Value < 100)
            {
                pb_splash.Value = pb_splash.Value + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                frm_inicial frm = new frm_inicial();
                frm.Show();
                this.Visible = false;
                //comentario
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inicia o projeto com CTRL+F5.   Ou vai em Debug -> Start Without Debug

Comment: Funcionou, mas existe algum problema em si com o debug no meu caso ?

Comment: Não, isso é padrão do Visual Studio. Quando você executa debugando, existem outro processos "atachados" ao seu programa que o monitoram, por isso continua rodando mesmo quando você fecha sua tela.

Comment: coloca o código do Program.cs e do frm_gerenciamento

Comment: Não estou conseguindo fazer outros blocos para postar o que pediu.. tem como ajudar nessa tambem ?

Comment: como outros blocos ? editando a pergunta ?

Comment: Acho que o melhor a fazer é clonar o seu projeto e sair tirando tudo o que não influencia no problema. Aí vc posta o código todo aqui.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis sim, não estou conseguindo

Comment: @FabioAragão clique aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/226047/edit e para formatar o texto, dê 4 espaços antes do bloco de código, ou o coloque entre dois acentos agudos ``` para separar os blocos, apenas salte a linha e escreva algo sem obedecer a essa formatação

Comment: Tentei e não funcionou

Comment: @FabioAragão o problema é que você inicia a aplicação pelo SplashScreen, e se continuar assim, quando os usuários fechar a aplicação, ela continuará rodando na máquina, sem ser acessível.

Comment: veja a resposta, se quiser mais detalhes, coloca o codigo da `SplashScreen` também... rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você inicia a aplicação com a SplashScreen, isso faz com que a aplicação continue rodando depois que você fecha os outros forms, possivelmente após o login você está dando um `Hide()` na Splash.

Se o seu form principal da aplicação é o `frm_gerenciamento` ele que deve estar no `Application.Run(new frm_gerenciamento());` e não o `SplashScreen`.

Para fazer isso, pode ser feito algo assim:

No Program.cs:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


        FormLogin form = new FormLogin();
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             Application.Run(new frm_gerenciamento());
        }
        else
            Application.Exit();
    }
```

No FormLogin:

```
   Load()
   {
      //Mostra sua splashScreen se quiser... 
   }

   btnLogin_click()
   {
      if([validar login])
      {
          this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
      }
      else 
          //Login inválido

   }

   btnCancelar_click()
   {
       this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
   }
```

Comment: +1 Boa! Explicou o motivo do problema, enquanto eu só foquei na solução.

Comment: @Rovann eu não consegui fazer o formLogin, não consegui encaixa-lo no meu codigo. Pode ajudar ?

Comment: @FabioAragão sim, mostre o que você já fez

Comment: vi o código da splash e, não faria isso...rs a tela não faz nada a não ser atrasar a abertura, rs só faz algum sentido se tiver alguma propaganda nela, acho que não é o caso. Por hora, deixe sem a splash e foca no login e form principal.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode iniciar a sua aplicação sem indicar uma instância de `Form` ao método `Run`, dando `Show` no frm antes do `Run`. Assim:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();

        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Fazendo isso, você tem que chamar `Application.Exit()` explicitamente para terminar a aplicação.

Você pode implementar os Forms para que façam isso automaticamente quando a contagem de forms abertos for zero (`Application.OpenForms.Count == 0)`. Para isso terá de implementar o evento `OnFormClosed` em todos os forms. Por exemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count == 0)
            Application.Exit();
    }
}
```